# How to build after "go get -d"?

Tags: go

I'm using the GOfax.IP which I can download and build with:

```
go get github.com/gonicus/gofaxip/...
```

This works without any problems.

Now I want to make a small change in the source code before compiling.

I know that I can use `go get -d` to only download the sources, but how would I start the build/compile part of `got get` after I finished my modifications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
 go install ...
```

This seems to do exactly the same as `go get` after downloading the sources.

Answer (score 0):

`go -h` can help you:

> Go is a tool for managing Go source code.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>     go command [arguments]
> ```
>
> The commands are:
>
> ```
>     build       compile packages and dependencies
> ```
>
> ...